# Converting "character" to "POSIX" in R

Tags: r, lubridate

I'm new to R and trying to replicate my current excel reports in R. I have a multi-column csv file with a column containing a timestamp in the format of "4/18/2022, 2:15 PM" (copied directly from the datafile). Ultimately I need to extract the week number and day number for each row in the csv.

I've gotten this far in converting the char to POSIX.

```
datetest = ("4/18/2022, 12:53:22 AM")
datetest1 <- mdy_hms(datetest)
print(datetest1)
sapply(datetest1, class)
```

which produces

```
> datetest = ("4/18/2022, 12:53:22 AM")
> datetest1 <- mdy_hms(datetest)
> print(datetest1)
[1] "2022-04-18 00:53:22 UTC"
> sapply(datetest1, class)
     [,1]     
[1,] "POSIXct"
[2,] "POSIXt"
```

But my problem is when I try to convert the entire column

```
#import CSV
RawData <- read.csv("data.csv",header = TRUE, ",")
#convert TS to POSIX
#column header is Date.Time.Opened
escRawData[['Date.Time.Opened']] <- mdy_hms(escRawData[['Date.Time.Opened']])
```

which gives me this

```
> escRawData <-read.csv("report1650637729324.csv",header = TRUE, ",")
> #convert TS to POSIX
> escRawData[['Date.Time.Opened']] <- mdy_hms(escRawData[['Date.Time.Opened']])
Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
```

which has cleared all the data from the dataframe. I used sapply to check the datatype in the CSV and I know that the data is "character."

I've read/watched a number of tutorials describing lubridate and the POSIXlt commands all giving more or less the same error of "no formats found" so obviously, I am missing something basic. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you post `dput(head(escRawData[['Date.Time.Opened']]))` in your question

Comment: Note that in your question you talked of `"4/18/2022, 2:15 PM"` yet in the example you used `"4/18/2022, 12:53:22 AM"`. These two are different. One has seconds the other does not. So how does your data look like??

Comment: We have a nice [tutorial for minimal working examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) I suggest you to read, before posting actually. Cheers!

Comment: As requested by KU99 here is the output 
> dput(head(escRawData[['Date.Time.Opened']]))
c("4/18/2022, 12:06 AM", "4/18/2022, 12:06 AM", "4/18/2022, 12:10 AM", 
"4/18/2022, 12:10 AM", "4/18/2022, 12:19 AM", "4/18/2022, 12:26 AM"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Everyone, I found out what I was doing wrong. @KU99's comment helped me figure it out. My actual data file did not include seconds in the time stamp. When I changed to using

```
escRawData[['Date.Time.Opened']] <- mdy_hm(escRawData[['Date.Time.Opened']])
```

it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

With your current code, one faulty date entry (format-wise or other) breaks the whole column's conversion. You could inspect the raw data beforehand, or transform them **rowwise** and check for failed conversions (**NA**s) like:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

converted_data <-
    escRawData %>%
      rowwise %>% ## important
      mutate(date_converted = mdy_hms(Date.Time.Opened))

## which rows went wrong?
converted_data %>%
    filter(is.na(date_converted))
```